# How can I edit the slideshow size in BigCartel (Luna theme)?

Tags: bigcartel

I am currently using the 'Luna Theme' on Big Cartel and cannot find a way to edit the size of the slideshow. There doesn't seem to be any button to customise but I'm wondering if perhaps there is a way to do it in the code? I don't know any code so am hoping that it will be simple. If someone could walk me through it that would be great!